# What is the memory issue in this RegEx function

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to scrape a web page for email addresses. I almost have it working, but there seems to be some kind of huge memory error that makes the page freeze when my script loads.

This is what I have:

```
var bodyText = document.body.textContent.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(' '); // Location to pull our text from. In this case it's the whole body

    var r = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])", 'i');
    function validateEmail(string) {
        return r.test(string);
    }

    var domains = [];
    var domain;
    for (var i = 0; i < bodyText.length; i++){
        domain = bodyText[i].toString();
        if (validateEmail(domain)) {
            domains.push(domain);
        }           
    }
```

The only thing I can think of is that the email validating function I'm using is a 32 step expression and the [page I'm running it on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) returns with over 3,000 parts, but I feel like this should be possible.

Here is a script that reproduces the error:

```
var str = "help.yahoo.com/us/tutorials/cg/mail/cg_addressguard2.html"; 
var r = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-‌​z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])", 'i'); 
console.log("before:"+(new Date())); 
console.log(r.test(str)); 
console.log("after:"+(new Date()));`
```

What can I do to overcome the memory issue?

Comment: Try declaring your regex as `var r = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])/i;`. Does the code run any better?

Comment: We need (in the question itself) a sample input set to run this against that causes this issue.

Comment: Hey man, this is an email extraction routine for spam pourposes isn´t it?

Comment: You can try to use indexOf("@") before exec the regex to avoid some regex test in strings that doesn't have '@'.

Comment: @stribizhev Would that matter? I thought the biggest difference was when the regex was compiled.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I feel like I was pretty clear. If you go to the page that I linked to in my question and run the code that I posted the page will hang. I am trying to figure out how to make it so this doesn't happen.

Comment: @mascaliente We have a specific requirement that everything we need to reproduce your problem should be in the question itself; not as a link. There are a few reasons for that, not the least of which is that if the code on that page ever changes, your question becomes invalid (and not useful to others to see if it applies to them). That's why links should be supplemental; we should be able to reproduce this problem on our own just using the code from reading your question.

Comment: You can reproduce with this code:

Comment: `var str = "http://help.yahoo.com/us/tutorials/cg/mail/cg_addressguard2.html";
var r = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])", 'i');
console.log("before:"+(new Date()));
console.log(r.test(str));
console.log("after:"+(new Date()));`

Comment: Thanks @LeonardoCarreiro. I'll paste that into my question instead of the comma separated version of the array that `bodyText` returns!

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr actually this is for a salesforce chrome extension

Comment: @GeorgeStocker is it acceptable now?

Comment: @mascaliente There's still no HTML that shows us what you're traversing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker due to the character limit on here I can't paste the page in. It is a huge page and the `bodyText` array ends up with over 3,000 nodes. I don't really know what you're expecting me to do. The code that I posted will make most any page hang

Comment: @mascaliente If your assertion is true (the code I posted would make almost any page hang) then you'll need to provide the HTML necessary for that to happen. So provide a sample HTML that causes this to show up.

Comment: The problem is not the HTML, it is only when r.test exec in the string "http://help.yahoo.com/us/tutorials/cg/mail/cg_addressguard2.html"

Comment: I still see a problem with using a RegExp constructor with single-escaped special characters. [Use double escapes](http://jsfiddle.net/vro01v8t/).

Comment: Rule out the expression. Use `[^@]+@[^@]+` as a test. Then try something better .. `"[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*"`

Comment: Here's a function that will get most e-mails.  It's not as strict as your regex but it's a lot faster. Test it with the kind of emails you're looking for and see if it works for you. function getEmails(str) {
  var r = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/ig;
  var emails = [];
  var e = null;
  var n = 0;

  while ((e = r.exec(str)) !== null) {
    emails[n++] = e[0];
  }
  
  return emails;
}

Comment: but don't use r.exec because you're not interested in the matched text, use r.test that is faster than r.exec...

Comment: @wolfhammer: If you think you have a solution, post it as an answer (as I see you did).  Comments full of unformatted source code are worse than useless; they're hard to read, and certain characters (like `*` and ``\``) tend to get dropped because the system treats them as markup.  At the very least, use backticks to format the code, like [sln did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538588/what-is-the-memory-issue-in-this-regex-function#comment49151848_30538588).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) has pointed out the solution in the comment: specify the regex in RegExp *literal* syntax. Another solution, as shown in the comment by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln), is to escape `\` in the string literal properly.

*I will not address what is the correct regex to validating/matching email address with regex in this answer, since it has been rehashed many times over.*

---

To demonstrate what causes the problem, let us print the string passed to RegExp constructor to the console. Did you notice that some `\` are missing?

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])
               ^               ^               ^                                                 ^
```

The string above is what the RegExp constructor sees and compiles.

- `/` only needs to be escaped in RegExp literal (since RegExp literals are delimited by `/`), and doesn't need to be escaped in the string passes to RegExp constructor, so the omission doesn't cause any problem.

  Below are equivalent examples showing how to write a regex to match `/` with RegExp literal and RegExp constructor:

  ```
  /\//;
  new RegExp("/");
  ```
- However, since `\` in `\.` is not properly escaped in the string, instead of matching literal `.`, it allows any character (except for line separator) to be matched.

  As a result, from being perfectly fine solution, these parts in the regex suffers from catastrophic backtracking:

  ```
  (?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  (?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+
  ```

  Since `.` can match any character, the fragments above degenerates to the classic catastrophic backtracking pattern `(A*)*`. By reducing the power of the regex to its strict subset, you can see the problem more clearly:

  ```
  (?:a[a]+)*
  (?:[a](?:[a]*[a])?a)+
  ```

---

This is the solution with RegExp literal, which is the same as specified in the string literal in the question. You got the escape for RegExp literal done properly, but instead use it in RegExp constructor:

```
var r = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])/i;
```

As for equivalent RegExp constructor solution:

```
var r = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])", "i");
```

Comment: I replaced the regex in my answer with yours and it matches more emails and there isn't a noticeable change in performance.  This is very cool.

Comment: @wolfhammer: The regex is from the question. I didn't make any change, except for slight syntax mistakes which causes catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but the first thing you need to do is to reduce the amount of text parts you have to test with your "corrected" pattern. In your html example file, you have about 3300 text strings to test with a regex. Keep in mind that using a regex has a cost, so removing useless text part is a priority:

```
var textParts = document.body.textContent
               .split(/\s+/) // see the note
               .filter(function(part) {
                   return part.length > 4 && part.length < 255 && part.indexOf('@') > 1; 
               });
               
alert(textParts.join("\n"));
```

Now you have only ~50 text parts to test.

**note**: if you want to take in account email addresses with spaces inside double quotes, you can try to change:

`.split(/\s+/)`

to

`.split(/(?=[\s"])((?:"[^"\n\\]*(?:\\.[^"\n\\]*)*"[^"\s]*)*)(?:\s+|$)/)`

*(without any warranty)*

**About your pattern**: the mistake in your pattern is already pointed by other answers and comments, but note that you can probably obtain the same result (the same matches) faster with this one:

```
/\b\w[!#-'*+\/-9=?^-~-]*(?:\.[!#-'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\b/i
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but you did help me and for that you deserve upvotes. My plugin is running much quicker now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a less strict regex that's fast.

```js
function getEmails(str) {
  var r = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/ig;
  var emails = [];
  var e = null;
  var n = 0;
  while ((e = r.exec(str)) !== null) {
    emails[n++] = e[0];
  }
  return emails;
}

function emailTest() {
   var str = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
   var emails = getEmails(str);
   document.getElementById('found').innerHTML=emails.join("\n");
}

emailTest();
```

```css
#found {
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<pre id="email_test">
  test@test.test
  foo@bar.baz.test
  foo@bar.baz.longdomain
  foo-bar@foo.bar
  foo_bar99@foo.bar
  foo@foo@foo.bar
  foo$bar#33@test.test
  foo+bar-baz%99@someplace.top
</pre>

<pre id="found"></pre>
```